# Set tomcat 7 system property in maven plug in

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, catalina, maven-tomcat-plugin

I am using embedded tomcat 7.0.54 in my webapp.While launching the web app,i get

```
processAnnotationsJar : Unable to process Jar entry javaassist-3.20.0.jar for annotations
```

I tried to look up and it looks like a common problem.To solve this i followed http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp ,https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/39145268/sdk-5.10.0-severe-error-javassist-3.20.0-ga-eofexception and https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat6-maven-plugin/examples/add-system-properties.html.

I am trying to add system property as follows to skip jar scanning for javaassist-*.jar.

```
  <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
       <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
       <systemProperties>
         <tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip>javassist-*.jar</tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip>
```

However it does not solve the problem.Is this a right way to add system property in embedded tomcat7? Is this a correct way to solve this exception?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to extend the embedded Tomcat and implement your own fast jar scanner as mentioned here: [Embedded Tomcat with Servlet 3.0 - How to skip certain jars when scanning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616431/embedded-tomcat-with-servlet-3-0-how-to-skip-certain-jars-when-scanning)